# Strange issue when closing a PyGTK application

Tags: python, pygtk, quit

I encounter a strange issue when closing a PyGTK application. This is the function used to quit the program:

```
def quit(self, obj=None, event=None):
        gtk.main_quit()
        os._exit(0)
```

When this function is called, the application's window remain on screen, but the GUI is frozen. In the terminal emulator I am returned to the prompt line while in the task manager the Python process is still running (using about 900k of RAM memory). I have to kill the python process to make the window dissapear.

What's happening? I should mention that I use threads and the application creates a HTTP server using SimpleHTTPServer and SocketServer .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `.serve_forever()` method of the `SocketServer`, you should probably call `.shutdown()` in `quit`.

Comment: I was doing this in a function, but never called that function. Thanks!